# Bootstrap navbar-default hiding form content

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently building an MVC in PHP, and on m login page, the Bootstrap 3.3.7 navbar if hiding my form content.
`<nav class="navbar navbar-default>` seems to hide the form content, where as `<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">` shows the content, it simply doen't allow the user to enter any information into the text fields.
Thanks for the help,
Luke.

EDIT: The HTML is

```
<?php
  $menu = Router::getMenu('menu_acl');
  $currentPage = currentPage();
?>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main_menu" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main_menu">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <?php foreach($menu as $key => $val):
          $active = '' ?>
          <?php if(is_array($val)) : ?>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><?=$key?><span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <?php foreach($val as $k => $v):
                  $active = ($v == $currentPage)? 'active' : ''; ?>
                  <?php if ($k == 'separator') : ?>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <?php else: ?>
                    <li><a class="<?=$active?>" href="<?=$v?>"><?=$k?></a></li>
                  <?php endif; ?>
              <?php endforeach; ?>
              </ul>
            </li>
          <?php else:
            $active = ($val == $currentPage)? 'active' : ''; ?>
            <li><a class="<?=$active?>" href="<?=$val?>"><?=$key?></a></li>

          <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <?php if(currentUser()): ?>
          <li><a href="#">Hello <?=currentUser()->fname?></a></li>
        <?php endif; ?>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

All functions in the code are working fine as I have thoroughly checked them.

Comment: @AlexAngelico I have included the code now

Comment: Please don't take this personally, I respect anybody who is trying to code, but here my first reaction was; "What a mess!". Sorry. This code is hard to read because there's PHP sprinkled all over the place. No attempt has been made to structure the code, not even with some indentation. My best advice, in this case, is: Try to separate the HTML output from the active PHP code as much as possible, and use functions or classes in the PHP code. You clearly use other code that has some structure, learn from that. Here's a useful link: https://phptherightway.com

Comment: @KIKOSoftware The reason why there is no indentation is because I was trying to get Stack Overflow to recognize it was code. Thanks for your help anyway. I have updated it now.

Comment: Ah, that's better... at least some indentation. 

Comment: I don't see a form.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware The form is on another page. It was this that was causing the problem. However, removing the first <nav> seems to fix the problem. I will definitely take a look at phptherightway.com.